# Python PIP : package directory does not exist

Tags: python, django, pip, setup.py

Since I uploaded my package to pypi, it seems that something is missing in my setup.py or MANIFEST.
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-audiofield/

When I try to install it :
**pip install django-audiofield**

I'm always getting the error :

**error: package directory 'audiofield' does not exist**

Comment: Did you fix it? If so, please update the question, @areski.

Comment: Looks like the issue is fixed, but I'd still suggest to read this article http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/08/14/high-quality-automated-package-releases-for-python-with-zest-releaser/

Answer (score -1):

This has been solved, I found an issue in the setup.py

I was reading args to check if "install" was passed and do some logic base on that. 
so "python setup.py install" worked fine but not from pypi.